# Why the tuple has a larger size than expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples, variadic-templates

I had the following definition of a tuple class template and tests for its size.

```
template <typename...> struct Tuple;

template <> struct Tuple<> {};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Tuple<Head, Tail...> : Tuple<Tail...>
{
  Tuple(const Head& head, const Tail&... tail)
    : Base{ tail... }, m_head{ head } {}

private:
  using Base = Tuple<Tail...>;
  Head m_head;
};

#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include <doctest/doctest.h>

struct Nil {};

TEST_CASE("test size")
{
  using T0 = Tuple<>;
  CHECK(sizeof(T0) == 1);

  using T1 = Tuple<double, std::string, int, char>;

  struct Foo
  {
    double d;
    std::string s;
    int i;
    char c;
  };

  CHECK(sizeof(T1) == sizeof(Foo));

  using T2 = Tuple<int*, Nil>;
  CHECK(sizeof(T2) == sizeof(int*));

  using T3 = Tuple<int*, Nil, Nil>;
  CHECK(sizeof(T3) == sizeof(int*));
}
```

I expect because of the empty base class optimization the `T2` and `T3` tuples to be a pointer size, but the result is different.

```
[doctest] doctest version is "2.4.9"
[doctest] run with "--help" for options
===============================================================================
C:\projects\cpp\cpp_programming_language\28_metaprogramming\variadic_tuple.cpp(21):
TEST CASE:  test size

C:\projects\cpp\cpp_programming_language\28_metaprogramming\variadic_tuple.cpp(39): ERROR: CHECK( sizeof(T2) == sizeof(int*) ) is NOT correct!
  values: CHECK( 16 == 8 )

C:\projects\cpp\cpp_programming_language\28_metaprogramming\variadic_tuple.cpp(42): ERROR: CHECK( sizeof(T3) == sizeof(int*) ) is NOT correct!
  values: CHECK( 16 == 8 )

===============================================================================
[doctest] test cases: 1 | 0 passed | 1 failed | 0 skipped
[doctest] assertions: 4 | 2 passed | 2 failed |
[doctest] Status: FAILURE!
```

Why is this and is it possible somehow to enable the empty base class optimization?

Comment: The code in the question would be much more accessible if it was written without that third-party library. Just write `main` and show the results of the `sizeof` expressions.

Comment: Why do you expect empty base class optimization to apply here?  `Tuple<Nil>` isn't empty.  It has a `Nil` object as a member.

Comment: As mentioned, every `Tuple` instantiation has a member variable.  Therefore no `Tuple` is "empty".

Comment: `Nil` is a stateless object type, but an instance of `Nil` is still an object. Each `Nil` member of the tuple is a distinct object with a distinct address and thus storage, even if it is stateless. The empty base class optimization only applies when a base class happens to be empty. `Nil` is never used as a base class here, so that optimization never comes into play.

Comment: I have not variadic variant of the Tuple class template and there the versions with Nil are only 8 bytes.

Comment: @bobeff Then you must have done something different there.  If you add that implementation to the question maybe someone can figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Empty base optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) only applies when you derived from an **empty class**. In your case, `Tuple<>` and `Nil` are empty classes, while `Tuple<Nil>` is not since it has non-static members (taking an address).

You have already enjoyed EBO in your implementation. `Tuple<int*>` is derived from `Tuple<>`, which is empty, so `sizeof(Tuple<int*>) == sizeof(int*)`. You don't need extra space for the empty base class here.

Since C++20, you could make `Tuple<Nil>`, `Tuple<Nil, Nil>` empty using attributes [[[no_unique_address]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address)

```cpp
template <typename... Tails>
struct Tuple<Nil, Tails...> {
    using Base = Tuple<Tails...>;
    [[no_unique_address]] Nil m_head;
};
```

You tell the compiler, that even though I have a member, I don't want it to occupy any space. Now `sizeof(Tuple<int*, Nil>) == sizeof(int*)` works.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/96MY49q1P)